# Самокоррекция sleep-loop в php

Tags: php, sleep

Нужно выполнять некое действие через заданные промежутки времени:

```
while (1) {
  // некое действие
  echo microtime(1)."\n";
  time_nanosleep(1, 000000000);
}
```

т.к. действие выполняется как-то время, выводит:

```
1449084599.4376
1449084600.439
1449084601.4402
1449084602.4414
1449084603.4427
```

то есть мы выполняем действие не с заданным интервалом, а реже. Как корректировать время чтобы выполнять действие именно раз в секунду?

```
$oldt = microtime(1);
while (1) {
  $newt = microtime(1);
  // некое действие
  time_nanosleep(0, 1000000000 - $newt + $oldt);
  $oldt = $newt;
}
```

вроде пашет, но по логам видно, что погрешность примерно та же самая

Comment: Вы считаете время выполнения одного цикла. А надо всех вместе взятых, я написал ответ с правильным расчетом и привел флуктуации. Более точно на php все равно не возможно. Системы реального времени надо писать на ассемблере и для них используются другие операционные системы

Answer (score 1):

На основе микротайма можно вычислять корректировку которую давать sleep'у. Только гарантии все равно никто не даст, за счет корректировок скажем можно добиться что бы за 10к секунд действие было выполнено именно 10к раз. но небольшой плюс минус межу операциями все равно будет. процесс же на компе не один работает, в нужный момент процессор может быть занят. А ядро ОС не может будить процесс с точностью до миллисекунд. Кроме того на современных компьютерах процессор может быть занят выполнением кода никак не подконтрольного операционной системе.

Вот такой пример:

```
 $start=microtime(1);
 $iter=0;
 while (1) {
   // действие
  $tm=microtime(1);
  $sleep=(1-($tm-($start+$iter)))*1000000000;
  echo $tm."\n";
  time_nanosleep(0,$sleep);
  $iter++;
 }
```

Дает примерно такой результат:

```
1449086740.7135
1449086741.7073
1449086742.7028
1449086743.7031
1449086744.7058
...
1449086811.7023
1449086812.7025
1449086813.6991
1449086814.7001
1449086815.702
1449086816.7025
1449086817.7029
1449086818.7023
```

Как видите, флуктуации есть, но миллисекунды держаться примерно на одном уровне. Считаю подход с вычислением времени с самого начала цикла помноженному на количество прошедших циклов гораздо более точным методом, чем вычисление времени выполнения одного цикла. Т.к. в значениях таймера так же есть флуктуации, хотя бы из-за округлений float в котором это время храниться и причин связанных с железом в ОС.